# Using ng-include into Spring Web Application does not work

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, angularjs-ng-include

I am trying to use ng-include in my web application based on AngularJS and SpringMVC.

This is the tree of WEB-INF directory:

```
/WEB-INF
    /views
        /fragmentPages
            footer.jsp
        index.jsp
```

In the dispatcherServelet.xml I added the mapping to /fragmentPages resources:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/fragment/**" location="/WEB-INF/views/fragmentPages/" />
```

Into the index.jsp I done this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        ...
    </div>
    <div ng-include="${servletContextPath}+'fragment/footer.jsp'"></div>
</body>
```

But viewing the source code in the browser I see this:

```
<div ng-include="/Project+'fragment/footer.jsp'"></div>
```

and the include does not work.

Why?

**UPDATE**

My tree now:

```
/resources
    footer.jsp
/WEB-INF
    /views
        /fragmentPages
            footer.jsp
        index.jsp
```

in my dispatcher I done:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/WEB-INF/**" location="/WEB-INF/" />
```

In my index.jsp if I use:

```
<div ng-include="'${servletContextPath}/resources/footer.jsp'"></div>
```

**it works!**

but, instead, if I use:

```
<div ng-include="'${servletContextPath}/WEB-INF/views/fragmentPages/footer.jsp'"></div>
```

not works.. How it's possible?

Comment: You don't need the `+` and the ticks `'`. The JSP-Engine just replaces the `${...}` where it appears in the jsp source files.

Comment: @meistermeier so, what I have to do exactly?

Comment: `<div ng-include="${servletContextPath}/fragment/footer.jsp"></div>` for this line.

Comment: @meistermeier, not work..

Comment: what's the outcome? it should definitely create the content `/Project/fragment/footer.jsp` if the servletContextPath is set as in your question.

Comment: @meistermeier, see my update please.

Comment: WEB-INF is a protected, non-public directory. You cannot include a page from there (in the client)

Comment: @meistermeier ok, I got it. So.. In what directory I should put the jsp that I want to include in other jsp?

Comment: It's impossible to include jsp files with client source code (angular) because they need server-side processing that compiles it to html. If you need templating have a look at server side includes like jsp includes.

Comment: @meistermeier, Then is wrong use JSP with Angular? Should I use HTML?

Comment: Exactly ;) You have to handle JSP and similars as source code files. You have to include an endpoint of your application here or use static html files you mapped like the other static resources. AND remove the mapping line for WEB-INF at resource mapping (you added in the edit). Anybody can see your jsp sources ;)